# Synthesize-able delay in Verilog

Tags: verilog, delay, system-verilog, synthesize, system-verilog-assertions

I want to synthesize a SystemVerilog code that has delay written as ##1 but the synthesizer gives syntax errors as delay is not synthesize-able. I want to know is there any way I can give delay that will be synthesized?
For instance, this is a SystemVerilog assertion in the code with delays

assert property ( ( req1 == 0 ) ##1( req1 == 1 ) ##1 !( req2 == 1 ) || ( gnt1 == 0 ) );

how can I synthesize this without losing its behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Properties are not part of Verilog, but a part of SystemVerilog. More to the point, properties themselves are not synthesizable either. Properties are used in `cover` or `assert` statements in a simulation environment.

As for delays, your only option is to use a flip-flop to delay the signal. In your property `##1` means "on the next edge" assuming that your property has some clocking related to it (either in the cover/assert statement or that it is within a clocking-block).

To create synthesizable cycle-delays in otherwise synthesizable code:

```
always@(posedge ck or posedge arst) begin
  if(arst)
    data_delayed <= '0;
  else
    data_delayed <= data;
end
```

Comment: Yes, you are right the properties in the code are specified using SystemVerilog assertions. I am actually trying to convert the hardware description code to a formally verifiable code. That is why I am using assertions to specify properties and passing them to the synthesizer to be converted for verification. The synthesizer is just not accepting the delay syntax used i.e ##1 in the properties. Is the above mentioned the only way to model delay for the synthesizer ?

Comment: You can't synthesize properties and I suspect that is not how your formal verifier works. In my (limited) experience with formal verification, the formal tool takes your implementation as one input and HDL properties as another. Thus the properties are not synthesized and can be written in the normal way. Perhaps you should ask another question where you provide more information about which tool you are using, and how you are trying to use it.

Answer (score 1):

The property you wrote does not make any sense. You cannot add delays in the middle of a Boolean expression. Did you mean to write a sequence of expressions instead? Then the correct syntax would be

```
sequence s1;
 ( ( req1 == 0 ) ##1( req1 == 1 ) ##1 !( req2 == 1 ) || ( gnt1 == 0 ) );
endsequence
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. That is the correct way, sorry my mistake. Thanks a lot. But still the delay syntax is to be used for the specified behavior and the synthesizer gives syntax errors because of that. It works fine for the properties without delay syntax.